# contain an Image whose size is dynamic inside a Div

Tags: css

i am working on this modal image viewer.
the problem is that i am unable to add a div which will be the container for an image.I need this div because i want to add the navigation buttons inside it. 
the point is the image is resizable according to the browser size.
the     max-height: 80%; is set for image css.
**I need the div to be the same size as that of image dynamically.**
Please tell me how to do it.

Here is the Html

```
<div id="imagePlaceholderContainer">
    <img id="imagePlaceholder" src="images/full/Full28.jpg" />
</div>
```

And here is the Css

```
#imagePlaceholder {
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    max-height: 80%;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the styles to the div not the image

```
#imagePlaceholderContainer {
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    max-height: 80%;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

#imagePlaceholder {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R49mW/

Your forked fiddle from the duplicate question: http://jsfiddle.net/wwbd4/

Comment: There is a Small Problem. the div is expanding to same size of browser and image is also 100% in it. I needed that the image size is max-height 80% and div just contain it..

Comment: I've put a jsfiddle up for you to see. It is working, do you have other code maybe that is interfering?

Comment: I've put up the question again with the fiddle. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761308/how-can-i-resize-the-div-dynamically-according-to-the-containing-image-size

Comment: don't put up the same question up twice, just edit the original question