# How can i resize the Div dynamically according to the containing image Size

Tags: css

i am in a Dilemma here.
i am working on  a modal gallery and the image css set to resize accoring to the browser window. Now i need a div around it so that i can place some text or buttons on it.
the image is resized fine but i am not able to set the containing div according to the image size.
I tried using the border red for containing div but it failed.
Please help.
here is a Fiddle to help you see what i am trying to do.
thanks.

Here is the CSS Code

```
    #imagePlaceholderContainer {
        border: 3px solid Red;

    }
     #imagePlaceholder {
        margin: auto;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 999;
        max-height: 80%;

    }
```

HERE IS THE FULL CODE-->
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BS72k/)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [contain an Image whose size is dynamic inside a Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760770/contain-an-image-whose-size-is-dynamic-inside-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `position: fixed`, otherwise you must specify a `width` and `height` on the parent `#imagePlaceholderContainer`.

Comment: Getting rid of Position:Fixed dosen't make the Border Red div fix around the iage. it just streches.

Comment: Sure it does - it only stretches because the parent is `display: block;` without a width set. All `<div>` fill their parent width  unless told otherwise.

Comment: can you fix the fiddle please.!

Comment: Nops! Not what i wanted.