# How to set the div at the end of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set this banner ad at the bottom of the page how can i let the image just take it's position in the banner div not to go over the above div.

```css
.banner {
    width: 100%;
}

.banner img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 140px;
    z-index: 99999999999;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="http://machahid.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pubmobile.gif" alt="ads">
        </div>
```

image describes the problem:
[image]

Thanks Guys.

Comment: May be, this can help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760770/contain-an-image-whose-size-is-dynamic-inside-a-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the container element (body or div etc) a padding-bottom or margin-bottom of 140px depending on how you've setup your document. This will always allow space at the end of the page for your ad to sit inside of.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution; don't use `position: fixed` for elements that must be contained within their parent. What you need it do is apply the `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` to `.banner` instead:

```
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

.banner img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 140px;
    z-index: 99999999999;
}
```

This will make the whole banner fixed to the bottom, with the image not escaping the bounds :)

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/t7bnm6o8/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply .. but i need it fixed to scroll it's an ad.

Comment: I've edited by answer to make the banner fixed. This will make the whole div fixed to the bottom of the screen, with the image occupying 100% of the width of the div -- and should be expected behaviour ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to avoid using `position: fixed` because it's known to cause  performance issues on mobile devices, especially when there is any kind of transitions or translations involved.

My usual approach in cases like this is to use an absolutely, or sometimes relatively, positioned element and then dynamically adjust the dimensions of the surrounding elements that need to fit in with [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc). This works great across all devices and causes no performance penalties. `calc()` is also [extremely well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Heading!</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <h1>Another heading!</h1>
    <p>...</p>
    <h1>Yey! Another heading!</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/600x120" alt="ads" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #981e32;
  width: 600px;
  height: calc(100vh - 120px); /* viewport height - fixed banner height */
  overflow-y: auto; /* makes sure there are scrollbars when needed */
}

.banner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  max-height: 120px;
}

.content {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}

.banner img {
  display: block; /* this prevents inline elements from messing up height calculations */
}
```

Just bare in mind that I've made some assumptions for the sake of demonstration. You are free to adjust the code to fit your needs.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/holodoc/pen/ZLLvee?editors=1100)**